# populate Jquery Mobile gridView Dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there is any way to fill jQuery Mobile GridView dynamically?

Normally we have to declare gridViews children class with ui-block_a,b,c as follows,

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block C</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

If there's any work around or plugins to achieve dynamic population for the gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can add the grid dynamically. Here is an example:

Given page markup like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="cont" role="main" class="ui-content">
      <button id="btnAdd">Add Dynamic Grid</button>
      <div id="dynamicGrid"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The script to add the grid on button click

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){    
    var html = '<div class="ui-grid-b">';
    html += '<div class="ui-block-a"><button>A button</button></div>';
    html += '<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" value="text 1" /></div>';
    html += '<div class="ui-block-c"><input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1"></div>';
    html += '</div>';
    
    $("#dynamicGrid").empty().append(html).enhanceWithin();
  });
});
```

NOTE: call .enhanceWithin() to have jQM initialize widgets contained in the grid.

### **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/nfrx9o6z/1/)**

Comment: you're adding a whole line at once, i need to add content of unknown amount one by one, i guess i won't be able to determine the grid order like this , correct me if am wrong or your way would work in my case and am not just getting it

Thanks for you answer @ezanker

Comment: @ayasalama, are you saying you don't know the number of columns ahead of time? If so, you might want to use an HTML table instead of the grid...

Comment: Yup that what i meant, thanks for the suggession, workn on it